# Drools : how to specify value in range?

Tags: drools

is there a better way to express this condition ?

```
$data : Data ( value > 20 && value < 50)
```

Something like :

```
$data : Data ( value in [20,50] )
```

Comment: Well first off, the `&&` is unnecessary in the first one, just use `,`. But why is your second way "better"? Sounds like an opinion.

Answer (score 2):

### DRL

No, the appropriate way of determining if a numeric value is between two other numeric values is how you've indicated -- by using two coditionals:

```
Data( value > 20, value < 50 )
```

---

There *is* an `in` operator, but it's not for this. It's for determining if a value is one of a set of other values:

```
Car( color in ( "red", "green", "blue"))
Animal( species not in ("lion", "tiger", "bear"))
```

---

If you're using the [temporal operators](https://docs.drools.org/latestFinal/drools-docs/html_single/#cep-temporal-operators_decision-engine), there's a syntax similar to what you've proposed for time ranges:

```
$eventA : EventA(this after[3m30s, 4m] $eventB)
```

... which is equivalent to:

```
3m30s <= $eventA.startTimestamp - $eventB.endTimeStamp <= 4m
```

But for determining the bounds of simple integers? No, just use two conditions.

### FEEL

The [Friendly Enough Expression Language (FEEL)](https://docs.drools.org/latestFinal/drools-docs/html_single/#dmn-feel-con_dmn-models) supports something like this according to the Drools documentation. Since I don't use FEEL, or DMN, or Business Central, I can't speak to it. But according to the docs you should be able to do something like `x in [ 1 .. 100 ]`.

But this is definitely DMN-only.

Comment: Just for precision, there is no strict relationship between "DMN" and "Business Central" and they stand separately, likewise editors and tooling are separate from Business Central. FEEL is the expression language part of the DMN specification. There is support of DMN via the Drools DMN engine. FEEL can be used separately from DMN if desired.